# rosrun & node_name

Tags: rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With the advice from Lorenz I was able to resolve the errors I had when running rosmake.  However I tried to launch rosrun but found that I am not using the correct node_name.  Actually, I (incorrectly) assumed that after rosmake run completed one of the outputs would the creation of the node_name.  Can anyone tell me how is the node_name created and where do I look for it?

Thanks,

Gene

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31944/rosrun-&-node_name/) by [SmithGeneP](https://answers.ros.org/users/2170/smithgenep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-04-16

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS there are separate names for packages, executables and nodes. Rosmake creates an executable file for each node. The default node name will be the string it passes to `ros::init()`, but that name can be overridden:

```
$ rosrun my_package node_executable __name:=my_node1
```

The equivalent `roslaunch` command is:

```
<node package="my_package" type="node_executable" name="my_node1"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anders](https://answers.ros.org/users/33655/anders/) on 2018-03-05**:
thanks for the info. A minor issue that: it should be

```
<node package="my_package" type="node_executable" name="my_node1"/>
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-05**:
You're right, I updated the answer.

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2018-07-03**:
This doesn't seem to be supported for all nodes. Specifying `__name` when running `rqt_image_view` is ignored, and the node still uses an auto-generated node name like "/rqt_gui_cpp_node_12409".